# Why is the magnetic field produced in an electric wire circular?

Tags: electromagnetism

If electric current is the movement of electrons, to what do the electrons in a wire get attracted to get a circular magnetic field?

Comment: That magnetic field is actually cylindrical.

Answer (score 0):

A batterie or some other source of  current or voltage drives the electrons through the circuit. The magnetic field is produce by the moving electrons.

Answer (score 0):

The circular magnetic field is derived by a curl operator, which imposes
a right-hand rule (this is a mathematical convention, so it could just
as consistently be done by a left-hand rule) and generates a "B field" vector
that does, indeed, take on circular direction around the current.

That B vector, however, is not a circular force, it is only a circular FIELD,
a mathematical construction which gives rise to a force through another
mathematical operation that has its own right-hand rule, the cross product.
The resulting force (the force is a physical quantity, not just a mathematical
construct) causes parallel wires to be attracted when they carry current in the
same direction, and repelled when they carry current in opposite directions,
and also acts on moving charge outside wires (Earth's B-field causes the
aurora borealis, for example).

It is necessary to use the complicated B field as an  intermediary, because magnetic forces
are too complex to be derived from simpler fields than are contained in a vector,
since those forces depend on position AND motion of charges, not just
positions.  A static electric field can be derived from a simple function,
called 'potential' (or voltage) assigning a numeric potential value to each
point in space, and associated electric force depends only on the gradient
of that potential.  The scalar field called electric potential gives rise
to the electric field through the gradient  operation that has no right
hand rule, and such electric fields are never circular for the same
reason that it can't be the case that your walk to and from school is
uphill both ways.

Magnetic fields CAN be circular.